# how to create component using Vue.component()

Tags: vue.js

i have created this component

xyz.vue:

```
<template>
    <button>
         button template
    </button>
</template>
```

I am trying to use it in component javascript like this:

```
vue.component('new-comp',xyz);
new Vue({el:'#app'})
```

It's not creating the button from `xyz.vue` in the vue app.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

you have to export xyz.vue below is xyz.vue component

```
<template>
<button>
     button template
</button>
</template>
<script>
   export default{
        data(){
          return{
             "your variables":"their values"
          },
        methods:{},
        computed:{}
 }
</script>
```

in component js you have to import above xyz.vue component. Assuming below is your main.js file(If we mention **Vue.component('componenet-name',component)** we are making our component globally)

```
import 'componentname' from './yourpath-to-xyz-file/xyz.vue'

Vue.component('global-component',componentname) //same name as imported
```

Now you can use 'global-component' any where as you wish (as it is global component you need not import it as we do for importing single(better to say local) file components )

[importing exporting single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)

[vuejs global components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)